# Why isn't my TD element wrapping around text content?

Tags: html, css

I have a table, where the left td takes the majority of the space, and the right td have very little space which forces the words to break.

I am trying to make so that both TD are the same width of the text content inside. I have done some research online but nothing I found fixed the problem.

Any help would be really appreciated! Below is my table code and css

**CSS:**

```
#order_info_container {
    width: 620px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#customer_service {
    padding-top: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align : right;
}

#order_information { padding-top: 20px; }

#totals_o {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <table id='order_info_container'>
  <!--This left td is taking most of the space -->
  <tr>
    <td><img id='o_summary_logo' src='o_summary_logo.png'></td>
    <!--This right td is being squished -->
    <td id='customer_service'><b>Customer Service # (646)-397-5751</b><br>
      Thank you for your business </td>

    <!--This left td is taking most of the space -->
  <tr id='totalswrapper_o'>
    <td id='order_information'>Order Placed - 07/01/14 12:18AM<br>
      <span id='order_number'>Order # - 775</span><br>
      <span class='conf_num'>Confirmation # - 81<br>
      </span></td>

    <!--This right td is being squished -->
    <td id='totals_o'>Sub Total = $28.95<br>
      Tax =   $2.57<br>
      Grand Total =  $33.52<br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the size of the image? it is more than 50% or less?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `table-layout: fixed` attribute on your table so that all cells have the same width. Example on [jsfiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nUpC3/1/):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>column1 Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>column2 consectetur…</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Also, the `fixed` layout will automatically give the same proportion of the length to any number of cells you have, i.e. if you had 2 cells, each one will be 50% of the table, 3 would be 33% each and so on… You can play with the fiddle to try this.

Comment: Okay Gotchya. What would be the purpose of the border collapse?

Comment: To make the cells *stick* to each other by the border (roughly speaking), but if you're not using borders you can remove it. Try removing it on the fiddle and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a width of 50% for your `<td>` in CSS should solve this problem. Having said that, 50% will work if you have only 2 `<td>`'s.

```
table td{
    width: 50%;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldxs5/). I have added a border in fiddle to show this effect clearly.

---

A better way would be to use the `table-layout: fixed;` property on `table` like @arielnmz recommends in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24502516/1369473).  It works best even when you have dynamically generated columns.  This way,  you won't have to calculate and define how much space a column takes.  They will always be equally divided.  So,  you should probably go with this approach instead.

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldxs5/2/)